Jetpack compose, ExoPlayer is destroyed late when changing the screen
To create a video player in Jetpack compose, I use ExoPlayer2. The problem is this - there is screen 1 on which the video player is located and screen 2. When switching from screen 1 to screen 2, the video player screen is displayed on screen 2 for about a second and only then disappears.
Tell me what could be the reason?
@Composable
internal fun ShowAboutCorpScreen() {
    val state = localStateEventEffectModel.current.state

    Scaffold(
        topBar = {},
    ) { contentPadding ->
        Column(
            modifier = Modifier
                .padding(contentPadding)
                .fillMaxSize()
                .background(SynergyTheme.colors.bgPrimary)
                .verticalScroll(rememberScrollState()),
        ) {
            state.aboutCorpData?.sections?.forEach {
                SectionType.entries.find { a -> a.name == it.code.uppercase() }?.let { type ->
                    when (type) {
                        SectionType.DESCRIPTION -> BlockDescription(model = it)
                        else -> {}
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
}

@Composable
internal fun BlockDescription(model: SectionAboutModel) {
    Column(
        modifier = Modifier
            .padding(horizontal = SynergyTheme.dimensions.x4)
            .padding(top = SynergyTheme.dimensions.x6),
    ) {
        Text(
            text = model.title,
            style = SynergyTheme.typography.textSemibold.copy(
                fontSize = Constants.fontsize.f22,
                lineHeight = Constants.fontsize.f28,
            ),
            color = colorResource(id = UIStyleR.color.textPrimary),
        )

        VideoPlayer(model.video)

        Text(
            modifier = Modifier.padding(top = SynergyTheme.dimensions.x2_5),
            text = model.text,
            style = SynergyTheme.typography.text1Medium,
            lineHeight = Constants.fontsize.f22,
            color = colorResource(id = UIStyleR.color.textPrimary),
        )
    }
}

@Composable
private fun VideoPlayer(videoUrl: String) {
    val context = LocalContext.current
    var isPlaying by remember { mutableStateOf(false) }
    val videoUri = Uri.parse(videoUrl)

    val cacheDataSource = CacheDataSourceFactory().createCacheDataSource()

    val exoPlayer = remember {
        ExoPlayer.Builder(context).build().apply {
            val mediaSource = ProgressiveMediaSource.Factory(cacheDataSource)
                .createMediaSource(MediaItem.fromUri(videoUri))
            setMediaSource(mediaSource)
            playWhenReady = false
            prepare()
        }
    }

    LaunchedEffect(isPlaying) {
        if (isPlaying) {
            exoPlayer.seekToDefaultPosition()
            exoPlayer.play()
        } else {
            exoPlayer.pause()
        }
    }

    if (isPlaying) {
        Box(
            modifier = Modifier
                .height(Constants.dimensions.d220)
                .padding(vertical = SynergyTheme.dimensions.x2_5)
                .clip(SynergyTheme.shapes.medium),
        ) {
            ExoPlayerLifecycleOwner(exoPlayer)
        }
    } else {
        Box {
            ImageFromSource(
                iconSource = IconSource.FromResource(
                    resourceId = R.drawable.about_synergy,
                    contentDescription = null,
                ),
                modifier = Modifier
                    .fillMaxWidth()
                    .padding(vertical = SynergyTheme.dimensions.x2_5)
                    .clip(SynergyTheme.shapes.medium),
                contentScale = ContentScale.FillWidth,
            )
            Image(
                modifier = Modifier
                    .size(Constants.dimensions.d56)
                    .align(Alignment.Center)
                    .clickable { isPlaying = true },
                painter = painterResource(id = R.drawable.about_play_video),
                contentDescription = null,
                contentScale = ContentScale.Crop,
            )
        }
    }
}

@Composable
internal fun ExoPlayerLifecycleOwner(exoPlayer: ExoPlayer) {
    val lifecycleOwner = rememberUpdatedState(LocalLifecycleOwner.current)
    val context = LocalContext.current

    DisposableEffect(
        key1 = AndroidView(
            modifier = Modifier.fillMaxSize(),
            factory = {
                StyledPlayerView(context).apply {
                    resizeMode = AspectRatioFrameLayout.RESIZE_MODE_FIT
                    player = exoPlayer
                }
            },
        ),
        effect = {
            val observer = LifecycleEventObserver { _, event ->
                when (event) {
                    Lifecycle.Event.ON_RESUME -> {
                        exoPlayer.play()
                    }
                    Lifecycle.Event.ON_PAUSE -> {
                        exoPlayer.stop()
                    }
                    else -> {}
                }
            }

            val lifecycle = lifecycleOwner.value.lifecycle
            lifecycle.addObserver(observer)

            onDispose {
                exoPlayer.release()
                lifecycle.removeObserver(observer)
            }
        },
    )
}


Use TextureView for the player surface.
You can find the relevant code on how to do that in the sample:
https://github.com/androidx/media/blob/release/demos/compose/src/main/java/androidx/media3/demo/compose/PlayerSurface.kt

Implemented the code in the demo and it works. Now the exoPlayer fades on activity transition.

I had a similar problem (back button had a very bad exit animation), unfortunatly I did not find any good solutions to this.
I had to settle to removing all exit animations of the Player screen.

As sdex said, one solution is to replace the PlayerView (in your case the StyledPlayerView) with a TextureView. Indeed, TextureView manages well the navigation transition:
AndroidView(
    factory = { context ->
        TextureView(context).apply {
            exoPlayer.setVideoTextureView(this)
            this.clipToOutline = true
        }
    },
    modifier = Modifier.fillMaxSize())

Unfortunately, TextureView does not support setResizeMode, so you should use setTrasform and a matrix to adapt the video.
AndroidEmbeddedExternalSurface or AndroidExternalSurface are very similar.
Anyway there is a workaround. I personally adopter this solution, which is to add transitionAlpha to the AndroidView:
AndroidView(
    factory = { context ->
        PlayerView(context).apply {
            resizeMode = AspectRatioFrameLayout.RESIZE_MODE_FIT
            player = exoPlayer
            if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= 29) {
                transitionAlpha = 0.5f
            }
        }
    },
    modifier = Modifier.fillMaxSize())

transitionAlpha can be any number between 0.1 and 0.9, try which is the best for you. In any case, with transitionAlpha, the navigation transition should improve.
Alternatively, you could try this other solution:
AndroidView(
    factory = { context ->
        PlayerView(context).apply {
            val view = LayoutInflater.from(context).inflate(R.layout.my_exo_player, null, false)
            (view as PlayerView).apply {
                player = mExoPlayer
                clipToOutline = true
            }
        }
    })

with my_exo_player being:
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<androidx.media3.ui.PlayerView
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    app:resize_mode="fit"
    app:surface_type="texture_view" />

